# Receiving PHP variables

Tags: php, variables

Having problems receiving variables, the error messages i am receiving are

Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpost.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: text in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\php\addpost.php on line 8

// HTML document

```
<div id="postdialog" title="Add Post" action="php/addpost.php">
<p>Please Fill in out member information.</p>
<form name="insertmember" action="php/addpost.php" >
<label>Title<input type="text" name="title" id="title"/></label>
<label>Text<textarea name="text"></textarea></label>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />  
</form>
</div>
```

// PHP file

```
if ($_POST['submit'] = "submit") {

    $title = $_POST['title']; 
    $text  = $_POST['text']; 

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
        $errors[] = "Title is Missing";
}
else 
{
    $title = $_POST['title'] 
    if (strlen($fname) > 15 ) {
        $errors[] = "Title is too long";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
    $errors[] = "Text is Missing";
}   
else 
{
    $text = $_POST['text'] 
    if (strlen($lname) > 30 ) {
        $errors[] = "Text is too long";
    }
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    print_r ($errors);
}
else 
{
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Comment: Typo: `if($_POST['submit']= "submit") {` should be `if($_POST['submit'] == "submit") {`

Comment: also you need `method="POST"` in your form tag,   and its `=="Submit"` since you use a capital S as your submit value.

Comment: Remove the `action="php/addpost.php"` from the `<div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have `method` specified in your form, so it defaults to `GET`.

You need to either add `method="post"` to your form tag or search for your data in `$_GET`.

Comment: Reference to GET as default form method: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: Also `if ($_POST['submit'] = "submit")` should be `==` ;-) Yet, I tend to lean more towards `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes didn't even get that far.  Seems like a lot of issues with this code as pointed out by other answers.  OP should read them all.

Comment: I edited my comment Mike. And yes, I agree. A literal "can of worms", as it were.

Comment: The question's like an old `VCR`, too many moving parts ;-) "Something's bound to go wrong".

Answer (score 0):

On a separate note... if you are using `$title = $_POST['title'];` twice with the second one without the `;`

same thing with `$text = $_POST['text'];`

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer is correct. You could also just use `$_REQUEST` to get the variable. It will get all things in post and get.

Your form line should be like this if you want to use post:

```
<form name="insertmember" method="post" action="php/addpost.php" >
```

Also please, it is good practice to do a check first before you assign request parameters to variables. Check this out :)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and $_POST['submit'] == "submit") {
    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
       if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
         $errors[] = "Title is Missing";
       } else {
         $title = $_POST['title'];
         if(strlen($fname) > 15 ) {
            $errors[] = "Title is too long";
         }
       }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
       if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
          $errors[] = "Text is Missing";
       } else {
          $text = $_POST['text'];
          if(strlen($lname) > 30 ) {
            $errors[] = "Text is too long";
          }
       }
     }

     if(!empty($errors)) {
        print_r ($errors);
      } else {
        //DO SOMETHING ELSE
      }
}
```

Comment: You have a few missing `)` and `;`, and a `}` and `if(strlen($fname) > 15 )` will throw an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in` error. Did you not test this before giving this answer?

Comment: Thank you Fred, I posted before I had the time to fully review it. I have made the adjustments and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers given ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21683960/) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21684018/)), already contain what is missing and what should be added, including syntax errors, so I won't repeat it in my answer.

Putting all of these together, have come to piece this **working copy** including a few additions.

The accompanying **modified HTML form** that was used for this, follows below PHP.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] = "submit") {

// can also use this instead of above
// if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $errors = array();
    if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
       if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
         $errors[] = "Title is Missing";
       } else {
         $title = $_POST['title'];
         if(strlen($title) > 15 ) {
            $errors[] = "Title is too long";
         }
       }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['text'])) {
       if (empty($_POST["text"])) {
          $errors[] = "Text is Missing";
       } else {
          $text = $_POST['text'];
          if(strlen($lname) > 30 ) {
            $errors[] = "Text is too long";
          }
        }
     }

     if(!empty($errors)) {
        print_r ($errors);
      } else {

echo "Success!"; // Added for testing purposes

        //DO SOMETHING ELSE
      }
}

else
{
// This message will appear if the code was accessed
// without the submit button being SET
echo "SORRY, you can't do that from here.";
}
```

### HTML Form

This: (sidenote)

```
<div id="postdialog" title="Add Post" action="php/addpost.php">
```

Should not contain `action="php/addpost.php"` only in the `<form>` tag.

```
<div id="postdialog" title="Add Post">
<p>Please Fill in out member information.</p>
<form name="insertmember" action="php/addpost.php" method="post">
<label>Title<input type="text" name="title" id="title"/></label>
<label>Text<textarea name="text"></textarea></label>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />  
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing i see is this:

```
if($_POST['submit']= "submit") {
```

and you should do `==` instead of `=` because you are comparing things, not assigning them.

Comment: And a capital S instead of lower case

Comment: -1 Keep the non-error related problems in the comment section

Comment: No capital `S` => `name="submit"` The capital `S` is in `value="Submit"` @PatrickEvans

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that was what i was referring to the capital in the value, this answer is testing for a value of "submit" when it needs to check for "Submit"

Comment: Oh Lordie, you're right Patrick. However, it's always best to use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead of checking if a value equals `Submit` isn't the best method. @PatrickEvans

Comment: @Fred-ii- agreed, was just mentioning the case sensitivity error lol

Comment: It's best to use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead. However, as Patrick outlined, it should be an uppercase `S` because of `value="Submit"` - `submit` is not the same as `Submit` in this case.

Comment: @MichaelvdNet i know i am new here, but this is part of the problem.
Fred-ii- thanks for editing my post.
PatrickEvans, yes it should check for "Submit" instead.

Comment: In a way, yes @Vladmir - However this `if($_POST['submit']= "submit") {` if anything should be `if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {` so you are 50% right and 50% wrong. ;-) and not `if($_POST['submit'] == "submit") {` it's not the same thing. Lettercase is important in this case.

Comment: @Vladmir the error (and thus the subject of this question) OP is getting is due to not setting `method='POST'` not because he used `=` instead of `==` (`=` would always evaluate true so that wouldn't cause problems)

Comment: @Fred-ii-you are right, i saw the missing = but didnt see the case sensitivity error.